# get android:windowSoftInputMode attribute programmatically on Android

Tags: android, window-soft-input-mode

I am aware that the android:windowSoftInputMode manifest attribute can be *set* programmatically using the following method:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
       WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
```

Is there any way to **get** this value programmatically? I do not see a corresponding getter method.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Found the solution, there is no 'convenience' get method but you can easily interrogate the window attributes manually:

```
int mode = getActivity().getWindow().getAttributes().softInputMode;
```